# with the excited ears

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "You mean Piglet. The little fellow **with the excited ears.** That's
>   Piglet. I'll tell him."

This is from Winnie-the-Pooh. What's the meaning "with the excited ears"?

Comment: It means "Piglet, the one who is known for getting excited when he hears things."

Comment: It's an unusual turn of phrase. I guess A. A. Milne partly meant Piglet's ears themselves were "excited" ([pricking up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prick+ears+up) to hear better). But obviously this implies that Piglet *himself* was excited, since once doesn't usually think of things like ears as being capable of emotions. And it would be a bit odd to suppose any allusion to ***excited*** in the "physics" sense (excited atoms, etc.) in a children's book. Don't read too much into it, and don't assume you can use this "device" in other contexts.

Comment: Although I've never encountered this usage before (or as with the cited example, I've simply forgotten it as a quirky "one-off"), I have heard things like *Hey! You with the flappy ears! Mind your own business!* when accusing a nosy parker of trying to overhear private conversation.